# Are there differences between returning early from an if statement or returning from both cases?

Tags: performance, rust

When writing a function that must return a value, there is two similar ways to doing so:

#1 (Extracted from [rustbyexample](http://rustbyexample.com/std/option.html))

```
// An integer division that doesn't `panic!`
fn checked_division(dividend: i32, divisor: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    if divisor == 0 {
        // Failure is represented as the `None` variant
        None
    } else {
        // Result is wrapped in a `Some` variant
        Some(dividend / divisor)
    }
}
```

#2 (an variation of above)

```
// An integer division that doesn't `panic!`
fn checked_division(dividend: i32, divisor: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    if divisor == 0 {
        // Failure is represented as the `None` variant
        return None
    }
    // Result is wrapped in a `Some` variant
    Some(dividend / divisor)
}
```

I used to write like the second snippet, but I've seen that in every example in *The Rust Programming Language* or Rust By Example they use the first case. Considering a match-all-possibilities code like the above, is it just styling or are there performance differences? Is the first one a good practice or its completely up to me?

Comment: The first variant is preferred because it uses a single expression to compute the return value. The second uses `return` to modify the normal control flow, which is not as clean.

Comment: For me it's more clean if you use the second one. And as stated on the chosen answer, it compiles to the same.

Comment: I'm just trying to explain why the first variant is considered better style in Rust, it has to do with Rust's heritage from functional programming. In the documentation it also says that Rust is "expression-oriented", that's why you don't need `return` to return a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), you can use the **ASM** and **LLVM IR** buttons to view how some code is compiled to assembler (machine code) or LLVM's intermediate representation. LLVM IR is usually easier to read, as it's more high-level than assembler.

[Let's analyze this code](http://is.gd/xrC1Jh):

```
use std::io::BufRead;

// An integer division that doesn't `panic!`
#[inline(never)]
fn checked_division(dividend: i32, divisor: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    if divisor == 0 {
        // Failure is represented as the `None` variant
        None
    } else {
        // Result is wrapped in a `Some` variant
        Some(dividend / divisor)
    }
}

// An integer division that doesn't `panic!`
#[inline(never)]
fn checked_division2(dividend: i32, divisor: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    if divisor == 0 {
        // Failure is represented as the `None` variant
        return None
    }
    // Result is wrapped in a `Some` variant
    Some(dividend / divisor)
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let i: i32 = stdin.lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
    let j: i32 = stdin.lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", checked_division(i, j));
    println!("{:?}", checked_division2(i, j));
}
```

(Note: I'm performing I/O to get values that the compiler can't optimize; constants are optimized too aggressively and the `checked_division` functions completely disappear, even with `#[inline(never)]`.)

First, let's compile this code in Release mode. What's the LLVM IR like? Here's `checked_division`:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal fastcc i64 @_ZN16checked_division20h2cc10ba72e80f410faaE(i32, i32) unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  switch i32 %1, label %next1 [
    i32 0, label %join
    i32 -1, label %cond2
  ]

next1:                                            ; preds = %entry-block, %cond2
  %2 = sdiv i32 %0, %1
  %phitmp = zext i32 %2 to i64
  %phitmp5 = shl nuw i64 %phitmp, 32
  br label %join

cond2:                                            ; preds = %entry-block
  %3 = icmp eq i32 %0, -2147483648
  br i1 %3, label %cond4, label %next1

cond4:                                            ; preds = %cond2
  tail call void @_ZN9panicking5panic20h77d028a733b1a80eiEKE({ %str_slice, %str_slice, i32 }* noalias nonnull readonly dereferenceable(40) @panic_loc3962)
  unreachable

join:                                             ; preds = %entry-block, %next1
  %sret_slot.sroa.0.0 = phi i64 [ 1, %next1 ], [ 0, %entry-block ]
  %sret_slot.sroa.3.0 = phi i64 [ %phitmp5, %next1 ], [ 0, %entry-block ]
  %4 = or i64 %sret_slot.sroa.3.0, %sret_slot.sroa.0.0
  ret i64 %4
}
```

And here's `checked_division2`:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal fastcc i64 @_ZN17checked_division220h9ae6c6af45a9a593DaaE(i32, i32) unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  switch i32 %1, label %next1 [
    i32 0, label %return
    i32 -1, label %cond2
  ]

next1:                                            ; preds = %entry-block, %cond2
  %2 = sdiv i32 %0, %1
  %phitmp = zext i32 %2 to i64
  %phitmp5 = shl nuw i64 %phitmp, 32
  br label %return

return:                                           ; preds = %entry-block, %next1
  %sret_slot.sroa.0.0 = phi i64 [ 1, %next1 ], [ 0, %entry-block ]
  %sret_slot.sroa.3.0 = phi i64 [ %phitmp5, %next1 ], [ 0, %entry-block ]
  %3 = or i64 %sret_slot.sroa.3.0, %sret_slot.sroa.0.0
  ret i64 %3

cond2:                                            ; preds = %entry-block
  %4 = icmp eq i32 %0, -2147483648
  br i1 %4, label %cond4, label %next1

cond4:                                            ; preds = %cond2
  tail call void @_ZN9panicking5panic20h77d028a733b1a80eiEKE({ %str_slice, %str_slice, i32 }* noalias nonnull readonly dereferenceable(40) @panic_loc3964)
  unreachable
}
```

If you compare both functions in your favorite diff tool (a side-by-side diff tool is better here, since there's a bit of noise there), you'll notice that the only major difference is that `checked_division` has a block called `join` at the end, while `checked_division2` has a block called `return` between `next1` and `cond2` – but the contents of these blocks are the same. In other words, the functions are completely equivalent.

Another thing we can notice is that the function *still panics* if you try to perform -2147483648 / -1 (the -1 test is part of the `switch` at the beginning, the -2147483648 test is right under `cond2:). That's because this particular division overflows, and [LLVM's`sdiv` instruction][3](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#sdiv-instruction) documents this case as leading to undefined behavior, so the Rust compiler gives your function well-defined behavior by panicking instead.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. Do you have any hint on why compiler ignores `#[inline(never)]` directive?

Comment: It's likely because the function does not call any other functions and the parameters I used are constants, so the compiler just evaluated the whole expression. I changed my code to use I/O to obtain values the compiler can't optimize and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Those two variants certainly will generate the same code. So it's just a matter of style. Standard style would be to use the first one.

Comment: The change was not dramatic, as the question is the same. You should have infered that was a typo.

Comment: Should I have? People sometimes put incorrect code in stackoverflow. Should I infer all errors are typos?

Comment: If I asked for a bug in my code or something like this, ok. But I asked for the issue of the style, so it was really irrelevant.